# Showing product view counter based on product attribute or categories WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, counter

I used the below snippet to display a product view counter on the shop page based on the ip address and it worked fine.

```
add_action('wp', 'product_view_counter');
function product_view_counter() {
 global $post;
 $userip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
 if ( is_product() ){

     $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_total_views_count', TRUE );

     $meta = (!$meta) ? array() : explode( ',', $meta );
     
     $meta = array_filter( array_unique( $meta ) );

     if( ! in_array( $userip, $meta ) ) {

           array_push( $meta, $userip );
           update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_total_views_count', implode(',', $meta) );

      }

   }
}
```

Show on Shop page,

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link','show_product_view_counter_on_product_page',5);    
function show_product_view_counter_on_product_page() {

global $product;
$id = $product->id;         
$meta = get_post_meta( $id, '_total_views_count', true);
if(!$meta) {
    $count = 0;
} else {        
    $count = count(explode(',',$meta));
}       
echo '<div class="custom-visitor-count"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><span class="counter-value">'.$count.' Views</span></div>';

}
```

The new idea is i want to display which 5 attributes or product categories have the most views on another page.

What I've done so far:

```
    $args = array(
'post_type' => 'product',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'fields' => 'ids'
);
$get_data = get_posts($args);
foreach ($get_data as $gd){

$product = wc_get_product($gd);
$color = $product->get_attribute('pa_color');
    
$args_color = array(
'post_type' => 'product',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
               'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                           'taxonomy' => 'pa_color',
                            'field'    => 'slug',
                            'terms'    => $color,
                            )),     
'fields' => 'ids',
);

$att_color = get_posts($args_color);
    
$att_color_sum = 0;
foreach($att_color as $ac){
    $color = $product->get_attribute('pa_color');
    $count_total_color = count($att_color);
    $productid_color = $product->get_id();
    
$meta_color = get_post_meta( $productid_color, '_total_views_count', true);
$count_meta = count(explode(',',$meta_color));
$att_color_sum += $count_meta;      
    
    $display = $color." ".$att_color_sum;
    
    }
    
 }

 echo "<p> Top 3 color attribute views : ".$display."</p>";
```

Output it gives a view like this :

**Top 3 color attribute views : Blue 15**

What i want is like this :

**Top 3 color attribute views :**

Green : 57 
Red : 42 
Grey : 24

*Obviously, I was lost.*

Anyone, please guide me so that I am on the right track.

Sincerely